# How to calclulate a derivate of a hypergeometric function w.r.t. one of its parameters?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Is it possible to take a derivative of a hypergeometric function w.r.t. one of its parameters and express it in a closed form?

I am particularly interested in this case:
$$\large\left[\frac{d}{da}{_2F_1}\left(1/2,\,a;\,3/2;\,-1\right)\right]_{a=2}$$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general the answer is no.

In the case at hand, however, the parameters are special and this becomes possible. One can use, for instance, the standard integral representation of the hypergeometric function to show that
\begin{align}
_2F_1\left(\frac12,a,\frac32,-1\right)=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}\left(1+t\right)^{a}},
\end{align}
which in turn yields
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}=\left[\frac{d}{da} {}_2F_1\left(\frac12,a,\frac32,-1\right)\right]_{a=2}=
-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)dt}{\sqrt{t}\left(1+t\right)^{2}}.
\end{align}
The last integral can be expressed in terms of dilogarithms (e.g. after the change of variables $t=s^2$):
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}&=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+s^2\right)ds}{\left(1+s^2\right)^2}=\\&=
\frac{\pi}{8}\left[1-3\ln 2 +\ln\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\right]-\frac{1+\ln 2}{4}+\Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^{i\pi/4}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-e^{i\pi/4}\right)\right)=\\
&=\frac{\pi\left(1-2\ln 2\right)}{8}-\frac{1+\ln 2}{4}+\frac12 \Im\operatorname{Li}_2\left(i\right)=\\
&=\frac{G}{2}+\frac{\pi\left(1-2\ln 2\right)}{8}-\frac{1+\ln 2}{4},
\end{align}
where $G$ denotes the [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: Perfect as usual ! Cheers,

Comment: Why in general, it is not possible ? For example, in this document, there is a list of rule http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap7.pdf

Comment: @optimalcontrol if you are referring to the rule at the top of the second page of the linked document, that is the derivative wrt to the argument of the function. The OP is asking for the derivative wrt to one of the parameters, in particular the second one.