# Integral $\int_0^\infty x^2\,e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x)\,\log(x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I need to evaluate this integral:
$$I=\int_0^\infty x^2\,e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x)\,\log(x)\,dx\tag1$$
I tried to do this in *Mathematica* and it returned a result of the form
$$I=\frac{(\pi+2)\,(1-\gamma)}{16\,\sqrt\pi}+\frac1{2\,\sqrt\pi}\left.\frac{d}{d\xi}\Bigg({_2F_1}\left(\tfrac12,\xi;\tfrac32;-1\right)\Bigg)\right|_{\xi=2}\tag2$$
I tried to find a closed form for the derivative using an integral representation of the hypergeometric function, but this way returned me back to my original integral.

> Is it possible to represent $I$ in a closed form that does not contain unevaluated integrals or derivatives?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below is almost a copypaste of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/549036/73025) to [equivalent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548232/73025) - which was asked one month earlier than this one.

---

We start with the standard integral representation of the hypergeometric function:
\begin{align}
_2F_1\left(\frac12,a,\frac32,-1\right)=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}\left(1+t\right)^{a}}.
\end{align}
Differentiating it w.r.t. $a$, one finds
\begin{align}
S:=\left[\frac{d}{da} {}_2F_1\left(\frac12,a,\frac32,-1\right)\right]_{a=2}=
-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)dt}{\sqrt{t}\left(1+t\right)^{2}}.
\end{align}
After the change of variables $t=s^2$ the last integral can be expressed in terms of dilogarithms:
\begin{align}
S&=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+s^2\right)ds}{\left(1+s^2\right)^2}=\\&=
\frac{\pi}{8}\left[1-3\ln 2 +\ln\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\right]-\frac{1+\ln 2}{4}+\Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^{i\pi/4}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-e^{i\pi/4}\right)\right)=\\
&=\frac{\pi\left(1-2\ln 2\right)}{8}-\frac{1+\ln 2}{4}+\frac12 \Im\operatorname{Li}_2\left(i\right)=\\
&=\frac{G}{2}+\frac{\pi\left(1-2\ln 2\right)}{8}-\frac{1+\ln 2}{4}.
\end{align}
where $G$ denotes the [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html). Note that  $S$ is precisely what we need to compute.

*Explanation*: 
At the first step, the only nontrivial integrals (producing dilogarithms) are $\displaystyle \int\frac{\ln(1\pm i s)}{1\mp is}ds$. The other integrals are elementary.
At the last step we used the formula $\operatorname{Li}_2(i)=iG-\frac{\pi^2}{48}$ from [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/03/02/).

Answer (score 20):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{I \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}\expo{-x^{2}}{\rm erf}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}
>      \,\dd x}$. Let's
>   $\ds{{\cal I}\pars{\mu}
>      \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x^{2}}{\rm erf}\pars{x}\,\dd x}$ such that $\ds{I = \lim_{\mu \to 2}\totald{{\cal I}\pars{\mu}}{\mu}}$

Since
$\ds{{\rm erf}\pars{x}
     \stackrel{{\rm def.}}{=}{2 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}\expo{-y^{2}}\,\dd y}$:
\begin{align}
{\cal I}\pars{\mu}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x^{2}}
{2 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{x - y}\expo{-y^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
{2 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta\,\cos^{\mu}\pars{\theta}
\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - \sin\pars{\theta}}
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r^{\mu + 1}\expo{-r^{2}}}
^{\Gamma\pars{1 + \mu/2}/2}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over \root{\pi}}\,\Gamma\pars{1 + {\mu \over 2}}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dd\theta\,\cos^{\mu}\pars{\theta}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
I&=\lim_{\mu \to 2}\totald{{\cal I}\pars{\mu}}{\mu}=
{1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\,\overbrace{\Psi\pars{2}}^{\ds{1 - \gamma}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dd\theta\,\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}^{\ds{\pars{\pi + 2}/8}}
\\[3mm]&+
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\,\overbrace{\Gamma\pars{2}}^{\ds{1}}
\overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dd\theta\,\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}}
^{\ds{\braces{4G + \pi - 2\bracks{1 + \ln\pars{2}} - \pi\ln\pars{4}}/16}}
\end{align}
$\Gamma\pars{z}$ and $\Psi\pars{z}$ are the $\it Gamma$ and $\it Digamma$ functions, respectively. $\gamma$ and $G$ are the $\it Euler-Mascheroni$ and Catalan constants, respectively.

---

$$
\begin{array}{|l|}\hline \mbox{}\\
\quad{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}\expo{-x^{2}}
\,\mathrm{erf}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}\quad
\\[2mm] =
\quad{{\displaystyle\quad\pars{\pi + 2}\pars{1 - \gamma} + 4G + \pi -
2\bracks{1 + \ln\pars{2}} - \pi\ln\pars{4}\quad} \over
{\displaystyle 16\root{\pi}}}\quad
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\approx 0.0436462
$$

Comment: I don't have that much experience with integrals, could you please give a hint on a substitution/contour to find $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2(\theta)\log(\cos(\theta))\,d\theta?$$

Comment: @Ian Mateus: For the evaluation of $\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2(\theta)\log(\cos(\theta))\,d\theta$, you can refer to [this calculation](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic297-50.html#p2007).

Answer (score 13):

$$I=\frac{2-\ln2}{16}\sqrt\pi-\frac{\gamma+\ln2}{16\,\sqrt\pi}(\pi+2)+\frac{G}{4\,\sqrt\pi},$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html):
$$\gamma=-\int_0^1\ln(-\ln x)\,dx$$
and $G$ is the [Catalan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html):

$$G=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a^{2}x^{2}} \text{erf}(x) \ dx$$

$$\displaystyle I(a) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-a^{2} x^{2}} e^{-t^{2}} \ dt \ dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} xe^{-a^{2} x^{2}} e^{-x^{2} u^{2}} \ du \ dx$$

$$\displaystyle = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-(a^{2}+u^{2})x^{2}} \ dx \ du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{a^{2}+u^{2}} \ du$$

$$\displaystyle = \frac{1}{a \sqrt{\pi}} \ \arctan \frac{1}{a}$$

Then

$$I'(a) = - 2a \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2} e^{-a^{2}x^{2}} \text{erf}(x) \ dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{- \frac{a}{1+a^{2}}- \arctan \frac{1}{a}}{a^{2}}$$

And

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2} e^{-x^{2}} \text{erf}(x) \ dx = - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \Big(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \Big) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\pi}} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a} e^{-x^{2}} \text{erf}(x) \, dx \nonumber \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} x^{a} e^{-x^{2}} e^{-t^{2}} \, dt \, dx \nonumber \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^{a+1}e^{-x^{2}} e^{-x^{2} u^{2}} \, du \, dt \nonumber \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a+1} e^{-(1+u^{2})x^{2}} \, dx \, dt \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma \left(1+ \frac{a}{2} \right) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+u^{2})^{a/2+1}} \, du \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma \left(1+ \frac{a}{2} \right) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{w^{-1/2}}{(1+w)^{1+a/2}} \, dw \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma \left(1+ \frac{a}{2} \right) \beta \left( \frac{1}{2} ; \frac{1}{2}, \frac{a}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2} e^{-x^{2}} \text{erf}(x) \log x \, dx \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \Gamma'(2) \beta \left( \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2} \right) + \frac{d}{da} \beta \left( \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}, \frac{a}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \Bigg|_{a = 2} \right) \nonumber
\end{align}

$\Gamma'(2) = 1- \gamma$

$$\beta \left( \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2} \right) = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{-1/2}}{(1+x)^{2}} \, dx = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{du}{(1+u^{2})^{2}} \, du \nonumber$$

\begin{align}
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \cos^{2} w \, dw \nonumber \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos 2w}{w} \right) \, dw \nonumber \\
&= 2 \left(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \nonumber
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

the calculation of $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{da} \beta \frac{1}{2}$$ $$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{a}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\Big|_{a = 2 }$$

From the definition of the incomplete beta function, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{da} \beta \left( \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}, \frac{a}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \Big|_{a = 2} &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\log(1-x)\; dx \\
&= \int_0^{1\over \sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1-x^2}\log(1-x^2)\; dx \quad (x\mapsto x^2) \\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi \over 4} \cos^2(x) \log(\cos x)\; dx \quad (x\mapsto \sin x) \\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi \over 4} \cos^2(x) \left(-\log(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k} \right)dx \; \quad (\text{Use Fourier Series of } \log(\cos x)\; ) \\
&= -\log(2) \left( \frac{2+\pi}{4}\right)-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\int_0^{\pi \over 4}\cos^2(x)\cos(2k x)\; dx \\
&= -\log(2) \left( \frac{2+\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{4+\pi}{8}-2\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\int_0^{\pi \over 4}\cos^2(x)\cos(2k x)\; dx \\
&= -\log(2) \left( \frac{2+\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{4+\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\left\{ \frac{\cos \frac{\pi k}{2}}{k^2-1}-\frac{\sin \frac{\pi k}{2}}{k}\right\} \\
&= -\log(2) \left( \frac{2+\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k(4k^2-1)} \\
&= -\log(2) \left( \frac{2+\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{G}{2}+\frac{\log(2)-1}{4} \\
&= -\frac{1}{4}+\frac{G}{2}+\frac{\pi }{8}-\frac{ \log(2)}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi \log(2)
\end{align*}